# Group 'for loop' output into groups of four

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a JS object array that I am using a for loop to print to the page:

```
// For loop through druid specs
for (let i = 0; i < druidSpecs.length; i++) {
  // Get spec
  let spec = druidSpecs[i];

  // Log Spec name, background, talents
  console.log(spec.name, spec.background);

  // Create spec containers
  html += `
    <div id="${spec.name.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase()}" class="container">
    `;


  // Loop through spec talent objects
  for (let i = 0; i < spec.talents.length; i++) {

    let talent = spec.talents[i];

    // If empty string, add empty talent box, else, add real talent
    if (talent.name == "") {
      html += `
                <div class="blank talent"></div>
                `;
    } else {
      html += `
              <div id="${talent.name.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase()}" class="talent" style="background: url('${talent.icon}')">
                <h2 class="talent-name">${talent.name}</h2>
                <h3 class="description">${talent.description}</h3>
              </div>
              `;
    }
  }

  // Close spec containers
  html += `
      </div>
      `;
}
```

If you're familiar with World of Warcraft talents then this may make more sense. The first loop creates a container div for each class 'spec'. Then each spec has 16 talent spaces that are grouped in rows of four.

As you can see I can get the talents to print in one large list within the spec container, but I have no clue how to wrap every four talent spaces within a container div.

[image: inspector]

Ultimately, the final html output would be something like:

```
    <div class="container" id="balance">
        <div class="tier">
            <div class="talent" id="improved-wrath" style="background: url('src/assets/druid/icons/0.png')">
                <h2 class="talent-name">Improved Wrath</h2>
                <h3 class="description">Reduces the cast time of your Wrath spell by ${value1} seconds.</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="talent" id="nature's-grasp" style="background: url('src/assets/druid/icons/1.png')">
                <h2 class="talent-name">Nature's Grasp</h2>
                <h3 class="description">While active, any time an enemy strikes the caster they have a ${value1}% chance to become afflicted by Entangling Roots (Rank 1). Only useable outdoors. 1 charge. Lasts 45 sec.</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="talent" id="improved-nature's-grasp" style="background: url('src/assets/druid/icons/1.png')">
                <h2 class="talent-name">Improved Nature's Grasp</h2>
                <h3 class="description">Increases the chance for your Nature's Grasp to entangle an enemy by ${value1}%.</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="blank talent"></div>
        </div><!-- End tier 1 -->

        <div class="tier">
            <div class="talent" id="improved-entangling-roots" style="background: url('src/assets/druid/icons/2.png')">
                <h2 class="talent-name">Improved Entangling Roots</h2>
                <h3 class="description">Gives you a ${value1}% chance to avoid interruption caused by damage while casting Entangling Roots.</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="talent" id="improved-moonfire" style="background: url('src/assets/druid/icons/3.png')">
                <h2 class="talent-name">Improved Moonfire</h2>
                <h3 class="description">Increases the damage and critical strike chance of your Moonfire spell by ${value1}%.</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="talent" id="natural-weapons" style="background: url('src/assets/druid/icons/4.png')">
                <h2 class="talent-name">Natural Weapons</h2>
                <h3 class="description">Increases the damage you deal with physical attacks in all forms by ${value1}%.</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="talent" id="natural-shapeshifter" style="background: url('src/assets/druid/icons/5.png')">
                <h2 class="talent-name">Natural Shapeshifter</h2>
                <h3 class="description">Reduces the mana cost of all shapeshifting by ${value1}%.</h3>
            </div>
        </div><!-- End tier 2 -->

        etc..
    </div>
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can you also provide an example for the `druidSpecs` object?

Comment: Here is a snippet of the object (the classData parent object is pretty huge) https://gist.github.com/jjchrisdiehl/e32165981c1733146842b20abd128f89

Answer (score 0):

One approach is use a `for` loop that increments by 4 and use `Array#slice()` within that loop to get each group of 4 items.

This allows you to create a wrapping element within each iteration of the for loop and iterate the sub group of items to put in that wrapping element

Basic example:

```js
const data = Array(10).fill(0).map((_, i) => `Item #${i+1}`);
const container = document.getElementById('cont')

for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i = i + 4) {
  const group = document.createElement('div')
  group.className = 'group';
  const items = data.slice(i, i + 4);
  items.forEach(item => {
    const itemDiv = document.createElement('div')
    itemDiv.textContent = item
    group.append(itemDiv)
  })
  container.append(group)

}
```

```css
.group {
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  margin: .5em
}
```

```html
<div id="cont"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a counter with the value of iterator variable (i) from the for loop which is going through Talents. I've modified your code to depict what I mean. You might have to slightly modify it as per your requirements. Hope it helps. Also, I moved the code appending the HTML to a function because we will now need to call it at 2 places.

**EDIT**: I've modified the code, instead of using i for the comparision, I've added a separate counter. And this time instead of checking for modulus, I'm straight up checking if the value of counter has been incremented to 4, when it is 4, I'm running the else condition and setting the counter back to 0. I think this will do the trick.

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import classData from '.\\assets\\classData.js';
import './style.css';

var druidSpecs = classData.druid.specs;
let html = '';

// For loop through druid specs
for (let i = 0; i < druidSpecs.length; i++) {
  // Get spec
  let spec = druidSpecs[i];

  // Create spec containers
  html += `
<div id="${spec.name.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase()}" class="container">
`;

  const buildTalentHTML = talent => {
    // If empty string, add empty talent box, else, add real talent
    if (talent.name) {
      //empty string is a falsy value, you can skip the equality operator
      html += `
         <div class="blank talent"></div>
         `;
    } else {
      // If empty string, add empty talent box, else, add real talent
      html += `
       <div id="${talent.name
         .replace(/\s+/g, '-')
         .toLowerCase()}" class="talent" style="background: url('${
        talent.icon
      }')">
         <h2 class="talent-name">${talent.name}</h2>
         <h3 class="description">${talent.description}</h3>
       </div>
       `;
    }
  };

  let talentCounter = 0;
  // Loop through spec talent objects
  for (let i = 0; i < spec.talents.length; i++) {
    let talent = spec.talents[i];
    if (talentCounter !== 4) {
      buildTalentHTML(talent);
      talentCounter++;
    } else {
      html += '<div class="tier">';
      buildTalentHTML(talent);
      if (talentCounter === 4) {
        html += '</div>';
        talentCounter = 0;
      }
    }
  }
  // Close spec containers
  html += `
      </div>
      `;
}

document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);
```

Comment: This looks pretty good! The only problem I am running into now is getting the spec (there are three in the druidSpecs array) container to close. Before, each specification would create a div, then the talents for that specific spec would be listed within this parent container. This essentially created the three spec trees with their constituent talents. Now it seems the parents aren't closing - full code here https://gist.github.com/jjchrisdiehl/c86798e82c72c024c6caa15b44a79e62 And here's what the inspector looks like https://cloudup.com/cqFEYpMfTkQ

Comment: I've updated the code from my answer, please check it out.

Comment: This looks like a good direction. From my reading of this counter, it looks like it prints four talents since the counter is under 4. Once the counter hits 4, it prints the <div class="tier">, prints one more talent, prints </div> then resets the counter and prints four more talents outside the tier. Ideally I am trying to have each group of four within a tier parent div. I'll look into this further and update if I figure this out  -  https://cloudup.com/cOFXR2VFRnQ

Comment: I figured something like this would happen, but I think it's good because now all you gotta do is play with the counter, you can try to debug the code in order to see what exactly is happening there, you probably will need to increase the upper-limit of the counter, but I think debugging will clarify this part a little better.